# Can't delete item from DB, tried several methods

Tags: laravel, laravelcollective

Can't delete product with any method combination. Tried with `<form>`, Laravel Collective `Form::`, and others.

I've looked around and there is similar issues like mine and none of the answers have solved my issue yet. Made several combinations.

View:

```
<form action="{{ route ('inventory.destroy', [$item->id])}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('delete')
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="submit">
        Eliminar
    </button>
</form>
```

Route:

```
Route::delete('/delete/{$id}', 'ProductController@destroy')->name('inventory.destroy')->middleware('auth');
```

Controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
        $product->delete();

        return redirect('/inventory')->with('success', 'producto eliminado');
    }
```

Delete button will always (by any method) take me to `/delete/{id}` instead of `/inventory` and throw a 404.

Also tried with these two and haven't had luck yet:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['ProductController@destroy', $item->id], 'method' => 'delete'])!!}
    {{ Form::hidden('_method','DELETE')}}
    {{Form::submit('Eliminar', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger'])}}
{!! Form::close()!!}
```

and

```
<form action="{{ url('/delete', ['id' => $item->id]) }}" method="POST">
    <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete">
    @method('delete')
    @csrf
</form>
```

I don't want to be repetitive but I can't get this work.

Comment: the path for the route should be  `delete/{id}` not `delete/{$id}`

Comment: Thank you @lagbox. That was the reason!!